# Get rows from 2 tables in one object

Tags: c#, sql, oop, object, select

I have two tables:

```
[Company]

 - CompanyID
 - Company_Name 
 - softID

[User]

 - UserID 
 - CompanyID
 - User_Name
```

In my backend, I have the following class:

```
Company 

 - CompanyID
 - Company Name
 - List<User> CompanyUsers
```

I am only using `System.Data.SqlClient`.

My question is:

How will I retrieve a company object with its users?

I currently have this method in my Data Access Class:

```
public Company getCompany(int _softID)
        {
            Company temp = new Company();

            conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM company WHERE softID = @softID", conn);
            command.Parameters.Add("@softID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = _softID;
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    temp.CompanyID = int.Parse(reader["companyID"].ToString());
                    temp.companyName = reader["company_name"].ToString();
                }
                conn.Close();
            }

            return temp;
    }
}
```

How could I retrieve my users of the company on the most effective way?
Would I need to implement another method in my DAL `getUsersByCompanyID` where I would pass my `temp`-object and loop through the rows retrieved by `SELECT * FROM person WHERE companyID = @companyID`, or is there a better way?

Comment: Is softID unique to each company in the table?  Or could more than one company have the same softID?

Comment: it's unique to each company

Comment: Do an `inner join` then when you execute your reader, you add the users to your list for your `Company` object. Should be easy since you are getting Users for that specific company

Comment: I believe then you would want to join your two tables together and then loop through the results building your users list.  So your query would be:

SELECT * FROM Company c JOIN User u ON c.CompanyID = u.CompanyID WHERE c.softID = @softID;

Answer (score 5):

One fairly simple way to do it is to use a query that joins the company and user tables together:

```
public Company getCompany(int _softID)
{
    Company temp = new Company();

    conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT c.CompanyId, Company_Name, UserId, UserName 
                                          FROM company As c
                                          JOIN [User] As u ON c.CompanyId = u.CompanyId
                                          WHERE softID = @softID;", conn);
    command.Parameters.Add("@softID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = _softID;
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            temp.CompanyID = int.Parse(reader["companyID"].ToString());
            temp.companyName = reader["company_name"].ToString();
            temp.CompanyUsers.Add(new User()
                                  {
                                      UserID = int.Parse(reader["UserId"].ToString()),
                                      UserName = reader["UserName"].ToString()
                                  });
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
    return temp;
}
```

The "downside" is that you constantly override the `CompanyID` and `companyName` properties, but it's a very small price to pay for doing it the easy way.

Comment: Don't need the `+` to concatenate the select statement since you have `@`, just a minor thing.

Comment: @penleychan good catch! I didn't even noticed that `@`, just copied the code from the question and changed a little bit :-).

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework do the job in **effective way**.....

Entity Framework (EF) is an object-relational mapper that enables .NET developers to work with relational data using domain-specific objects. It eliminates the need for most of the data-access code that developers usually need to write.

Entity Framework allows you to create a model by writing code or using boxes and lines in the EF Designer. Both of these approaches can be used to target an existing database or create a new database. This short video explains the differences and how to find the one that is right for you.

[Introduction to Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: Entity Framework do the job in an *easy way*. If you know your way around SQL, most of the time it's not as efficient as writing the SQL yourself. If you want an efficient ORM, go with Dapper, though it's a Micro ORM and you'll have to know your way around SQL to work with it.

Comment: i think "effective way" means "low effort" ?? its very simple to use in vs. its almost zero config....

Comment: So when you are talking about `effective way` you really mean `easy to write`. I though you are talking about efficient run time, which is not EF strong suit (though I understand the latest version are getting better at it)